# Aquiring win32 mutex in java

Tags: java, winapi, mutex

I'm extending a java application.

It should modify a directory that may be used by another process and long ago they have already agreed to protect the directory with a named mutex.

How do I aquire named win32 mutex?

Comment: ... thou the title is exactly what I need, none of the answers matches the question; the accepted one solves the underlying problem, not what's advertised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call some Win32 functions using whichever interop technique you feel most comfortable with. Here's the outline of what you do:

1. Call `CreateMutex` passing `FALSE` for the `bInitialOwner` parameter, and the agreed mutex name.
2. To acquire the mutex call `WaitUntilSignaled` passing the mutex handle.
3. When you are done with the mutex, call `ReleaseMutex`.
4. Finally call `CloseHandle` to return the unmanaged resource to the system.

You'll clearly need to perform error checking in the usual way for Win32 functions.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make use of JNI and write some native code in C.